# Future Meaning in IF clause

Tags: meaning-in-context, clauses

The weather can be rainy tomorrow. It is not accurate. The weather forecast application says that it will be rainy tomorrow.

Depending on this information, I have set up following sentence:

> If the weather is rainy tomorrow, I will not stop by my brother.

Is it a true sentence ? In many books, future structures are not allowed to be used in if clauses. In fact, I did not use "will", "going to" or any other kind of future structure in if clause, but its meaning is related to a situation in the future.

Comment: Can you give us an instance of the future being disallowed as you indicate?

Comment: The weather **may be** rainy tomorrow. The weather in Paris can be rainy. Can: a general proposition.

Answer (score 1):

The construction is correct. However "stop by my brother" sounds like he is standing out in the open and you plan to stop next to him. You probably mean stop by my brother's place/house/work/home. You could even leave out the final noun and just have "stop by my brother's".

Comment: Or more formally, 'visit my brother'.